# Problem in for-loop for add new input with a number increasing

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

According to the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wAwyR/11/), i want in each times adding new input with putting number in fields(1, 2, 3), number increasing in each one from new input adding to `name[+number increasing here+][]` in the input.

**[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/wAwyR/11/)** this example not worked true

**I want this:**

> if put to "field 1" number `2` we get tow new input that name it is
>   `name[0][], name[1][]`
>  in "field 2" put number `3` we get
>   `name[2][], name[3][], name[4][]`
>  in "field 3" put number `2` we
>   get `name[5][], name[6][]` and etc.

Code(how is, fixed val coming through as a string not an int!?):

```
var counter = 0;
$('input').live("keyup", function () {    
    var id = '#'+$(this).closest('b').attr('id');
    $(id+' .lee').empty();    
    var val = int($(this).val());
    for (var i = counter; i < val + counter; i++) {
        $(id+' .lee').append('<input type="text" name="hi['+i+'][]">');        
    }
    counter = val + counter;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: I re-read your question and believe I have a solution that has your desired behavior:*

The JavaScript:

```
var counter = 0;
$('input').live('keyup', function(e) {
    // bail out if the keypress wasn't a number
    if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) { return; }

    // get the current value of the input
    var val = +$(this).val();

    // don't do anything if we don't have a valid number
    if (isNaN(val)) { return; }

    // find and empty .lee
    var $lee = $(this).closest('b').find('.lee').empty();

    // create inputs
    for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
        $('<input type="text"/>').attr('name', 'hi[' + (counter + i) + '][]')
            .appendTo($lee);
    }

    // update our counter
    counter = val + counter;
});
```

Here's the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wAwyR/14/

Comment: Well, for starters, you changed all my code :). You're no longer casting the string value to an int (the '+' character out front was important). You are inconsistently naming the `val` variable (sometimes `val` sometimes `$val`). And `unique` isn't defined anywhere, so I'm not sure what that should be doing....